# AngularJS: how to get selected items from a dynamic list using "ng-repeat"

Tags: database, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm working in a web application. I have a user list that i get from a database and use ng-repeat to list each entry by name like this:

JS:

```
   $http.get("cretecampaign.php?action=getExecutives").success(function(data) {
        $scope.executives = data;
```

PHP:

```
   <form name="myForm">
     <li ng-repeat="executive in executives" class="no-dots">
         <input type="checkbox" name="usertoadd" ng-model="executive.addto" >
         {{ executive.user }}
     </li>
   </form>
```

I need to pass the user id of the selected users on the list to `myForm`, but i can't figure out how to do this. 
I've pass the last few hours searching for an example code but can't find anything like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the `$scope.executives` array in your controller to find out which users are selected. If a user is selected, they will have a `addto` property.

So your code might look something like this:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  var selected = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.executives, function(executive){
    if(executive.addto){
      selected.push(executive.user.id);
    }
  });
  //Do something with selected...
}
```